# Magento2: grid form fields are not display

Tags: magento2.3

Today I am trying to create admin grid form using ***ui component***. But field on form doesn't loaded It showing blank form. Admin grid created successfully.

**my ui_component/simpleimg_image_form.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form.simpleimg_image_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form.simpleimg_image_form_data_source</item>
        </item>

        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image Form</item>
        <!--
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
        -->
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form</item><!--manage_image-->
        </item>

        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="simpleimg_image_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Model\Image\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="simpleimg/image/save" />
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item><!--image fieldset-->
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item> -->
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                      <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image Id</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="imagename">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">imagename</item>
                    <!-- <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item><!--image-->
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">imagename</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <!-- <field name="url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Email</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> -->
        <field name="url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <!-- <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">url</item>

                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="simpleimg/image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="summary">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">summary</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">summary</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
           <!--  <field name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Comment</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> -->
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Enable Image upload</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                     <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

***DataProvider.php***

```
namespace  Magik\Helloworld\Model\Image;

use  Magik\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Image\CollectionFactory;
use Magik\Helloworld\Model\Image;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $collection;
    protected $_loadedData;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $CollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->collection = $CollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if(isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        foreach($items as $image)
        {
            $this->_loadedData[$image->getId()] = $image->getData();
        }

        return $this->_loadedData;
    }

}
```

**contorller file Image/Image.php**

```
//(Purpose: I use this file as a root controller and the action classes will be extended this controller) and insert this following code into it:

namespace Magik\Helloworld\Controller\Adminhtml\Image;

class Image extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
   /**
     * @var \Magik\Helloworld\Model\ImageFactory
     */

    protected $_ImageFactory;

    /**
     * @param ImageFactory $imageFactory
     */


    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory = false;


    /**
     * @param Context $context

     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * 
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        // \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ,\Magik\Helloworld\Model\ImageFactory $imageFactory

    ) 
    {

        ///////////////////
       parent::__construct($context);
        // $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->imageFactory = $imageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * News access rights checking
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magik_Helloworld::manage_image');
    }

    public function execute()
 {
/** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
 // $imageModel = $this->_modelImageFactory->create();
$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
$resultPage->setActiveMenu('Magik_Helloworld::manage_image')
->addBreadcrumb(
    __('Simple image'), __('Simple Image')
)->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple Image'));
return $resultPage;
}



}
```

Comment: Please provide error or logs

Comment: Have you check the DataProvider getData method? check $this->_loadedData have loaded data or not.

Comment: No any error generated

Comment: could you say in detail how to check this

Answer (score 0):

I update your **ui_component/simpleimg_image_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form.simpleimg_image_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form.simpleimg_image_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">general_information</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Block\Adminhtml\Image\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="simpleimg_image_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magik\Helloworld\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">simpleimg_image_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">label_id</argument><!-- your primary key -->
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">label_id</argument><!-- your primary key -->
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general_information">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <!-- <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> -->
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">url</item>

                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="simpleimg/image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="summary">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">summary</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">summary</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                     <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
<!--         <field name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Comment</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field> -->
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Enable Image upload</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">image</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

add DataProvider this path **Magik\Helloworld\Model**

**DataProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace Magik\Helloworld\Model;

use Magik\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Image\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $loadedData;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $imageCollection,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $imageCollection->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }


    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $Job) {
            $this->loadedData[$Job->getId()] = $Job->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**Update**
your action file like this

```
<?php

namespace Magik\Helloworld\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Actions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $urlBuilder;

    const URL_DELETE_PATH = 'routename/contollername/delete';
    const URL_VIEW_PATH = 'routename/contollername/edit';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item['id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'view' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_VIEW_PATH,
                                [
                                    'id' => $item['id'],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit'),
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_DELETE_PATH,
                                [
                                    "id" => $item['id'],
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you want to delete this ?'),
                            ],
                        ],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: No it couldn't work..again show blank form

Comment: Your table column name and form field name must be same.check to print print_r($this->loadedData->getData()); Please check and inform me.

Comment: check my update answer